# Connect manager not working at all - Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, downloader

I have a very serious issue with **Magento Connect Manager**.

I can able to login in my connect manager. It's not giving me any kind of error, even if I use wrong username and password. It's just simply redirecting me here:

https://www.domain.com/downloader/index.php?A=#

I tried to check the system.log but nothing over there. I also tried to place a fresh copy of the downloader, but it didn't work.

Please someone suggest me something.

Comment: You need this to install an extension ?

Comment: Yes, I need to install a new extension.

Comment: [It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

Answer (score 0):

Check if all files should be set to 644 and all directories should be set to 755 (instead of 666 and 777 which are not secure).

If you want to install some extensions, go to https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ copy the url extension install then download it in this site: http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

This method is temporary the time to find the solution to your problem.